# What is intended behavior of Guava's Optional.or()?

Tags: java, guava, option-type, chaining

A method where I chain optionals does not behave how I thought it would [from reading the docs.](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or(com.google.common.base.Optional))

Assume all `function_n` return an `Optional<Foo>`

```
public Foo getFooFromService() {
     return this.function_1()
         .or(this.function_2())
         .or(this.function_3())
         .or(DEFAULT_VAL)
```

I thought that for the above code, if `function_1` returned a non-absent Optional, then the program would return the inner value of it (the result of .get()) and not do any further computation on `function_2` and `function_3`

My program is for sure doing that additional computation

Comment: Hint: There seems to be an overload which takes a `Supplier`: *Returns the contained instance if it is present; supplier.get() otherwise.*

Comment: @qqilihq yes, I mentioned it in my answer. I challenge you to rewrite OP's snippet to use this method :)

Answer (score 5):

In order to return a value from `getFooFromService`, `function_1` and three `or`s have to be executed, meaning that their parameters will be evaluated. `function_2` and `function_3` will be run under any circumstances.

The option that might be suitable for you is the overloaded version that takes a `Supplier` which implies lazy evaluation.

```
public abstract T or(Supplier<? extends T> supplier)
```

**UPDATE**

It's a `@Beta` method (a subject to change), and I find it entirely useless. It resolves a `Supplier<? extend T>` to `T`, thus ruins the opportunity of building a chain. Basically, you can't rewrite your snippet to use this method.

**UPDATE 1**

But you could switch to Java's `Optional` and write

```
return function_1()
       .orElseGet(() -> function_2()
                        .orElseGet(() -> function_3()
                                         .orElse(DEFAULT_VAL)));
```

which isn't that expressive, but working as expected.

My formatting is awful, but you get the idea ;)

Comment: Oh I see that there is that ability now. I solved my problem by moving to Java Optionals and essentially doing what you suggest

Comment: @descript did you use `orElseGet`s instead? :)

Comment: I didn't get one thing, **why** is the overload expecting [`Optional secondChoice`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or(com.google.common.base.Optional)) not working as stated in the documentation?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Correct I used nested orElseGet( () -> function_n). Thanks for the updates to your answer! It is not quite as nice as simply chaining or()s but its not too much different, and certainly better than a bunch of if (isPresent()) then .get()

Answer (score 2):

## [Guava "gently recommends" to use Java's `Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

So use Java's [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) to write the rather legible code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().getFooFromService();
  }
  String getFooFromService() {
    return this.function_1()
      .or(this::function_2) // Requires Java 9
      .or(this::function_3) // Requires Java 9
      .orElse("DEFAULT_VALUE");
  }

  Optional<String> function_1() {
    System.out.println("function_1 called");
    return Optional.empty();
  }

  Optional<String> function_2() {
    System.out.println("function_2 called");
    return Optional.of("b");
  }

  Optional<String> function_3() {
    System.out.println("function_3 called");
    return Optional.of("c");
  }
}
```

You'll see that in this case, with the given setup, `function_1` and `function_2` are called, but not `function_3`.